# Connect chromebook to vpn with ovpn certificate

Tags: openvpn, certificate, chromebook

I'm recently trying to connect my chromebook to FreeVPN.me's vpn service. It uses OpenVPN. Although chromebooks support OpenVPN, they don't support .ovpn certificates, which is the only kind of file that site offers. Is there to make it support the .ovpn files? If no, then is there a way to convert it into another format that the Chromebooks support?

.ovpn file bundle: [FreeVPN.me-OpenVPN-Bundle.zip](https://freevpn.me/FreeVPN.me-OpenVPN-Bundle.zip)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. But you're in an universe of pain. I did this once for our users (since we provide configs for Linux, Windows and ChromeOS). Please look at this document:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/17DMcg0JLDSkrlD5jqhvnVbnzPx5vxCG0vjjSA8mPx70/edit?usp=sharing

You should probably contact your VPN provider and point them to that document.

Answer (score 0):

You can [enable developer mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/210817/how-to-enable-developer-mode-on-your-chromebook/).
Then you will be able to run the following:

```
sudo stop shill
sudo start shill BLACKLISTED_DEVICES=tun0
sudo openvpn <name-of-file.openvpn>
```

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/5xavcp/chrome_os_openvpn_connection_from_crosh_terminal/).